# Как реализовать такое условие на PHP

Tags: php

Как написать условие которое будет это проверять. Например если за месяц что-то добавилось в БД то выполнить то-то, например вывести Hello World?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В таблице, в вашей БД, должна быть колонка даты-времени (DateTime). Когда вы создаете новую запись, то указываете еще и время создания. Таким образом, будет понятно когда именно в базу была внесена определенная запись. Затем, если речь о проверке за текущий месяц, а не за какой-то конкретный, то достаточно будет получить время начала текущего месяца. в запросе это можно сделать например вот так:

```
date_format(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')
```

Теперь достаточно будет проверить, есть ли в БД записи с датой создания большей чем начало текущего месяца. Это можно сделать примерно следующим SQL запросом:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE created_at > date_format(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')";
```

Вы получите кол-во записей, которые были созданы после начала текущего месяца. Если это число больше ноля - значит за этот месяц в базу что-то было внесено.

Comment: Во всех БД есть встроенная функция получения текущей даты. Например в MySQL записи за месяц, т.е. 30-31 день получаются `where created_at >= now() - inerval 1 month`. Если текущий месяц то `where created_at >= date_format(now(), '%Y.%m.01')`. Таким  образом формировать дату в php вообще не требуется. Кроме того _никогда_ не подставляйте текст переменных в сам запрос, даже в таких случаях. Для передачи параметров в запросы _всегда_ используйте привязку переменных (функции типа bind_param драйвера БД)